# Highcharts spiderweb chart resizes axis after calling series.setData

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts spiderweb chart with series data that I'm updating via ajax every X minutes. When I initially load the page, it looks like this:

[image: spiderweb chart on initial load]

However, after the first and subsequent updates to the series data, the chart looks like this:

[image: spiderweb chart after first and subsequent updates with same data]

Note that in the sample, the series data used to update the chart is exactly the same as the original data used to initialize the chart.

Here is a [jsFilddle that reproduces the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/fC2GR/1/). Here is the line that updates the series data:

```
chart.series[0].setData([14, 10, 1, 7, 7]);
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load the page
2. Click the "Set new data button"

Am I doing something wrong when updating the chart?

Answer (score 0):

For some unexpected reason, you have to do step by step the creation of new Highchart as well as the update of your charts.

Check out my demo http://jsfiddle.net/pm7Cn/1/

Take a look how I declare my variables out side of the function, in order to have the ability to access them in the entire script.

```
var chart;
var flagIn = 1;
var options, series2, title2;
```

Also, have in mind that I initialise my "options" variable and afterwards I am creating the Highcharts object

```
options = {....}
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

In order to create new charts I am pushing my new data in series2 and Title 2 and then I am trying to update my charts object.

```
options.series = series2;
options.title = title2;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
console.log("update");
```

**Updated**
http://jsfiddle.net/pm7Cn/2/
On the fiddle above you can see how the same data polygon is loaded over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set min/max value or tickInterval as 5 ?

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval